# SQL Server 2008 maximum size on FAT32

Tags: sql-server, database, max, fat32

I am running WinXP with a FAT32 file system.

Does FAT32's max. file size limit of 4GB apply on the max. database size I can have?

(I have SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition, I know the free editions restrict DB size to 4GB, having nothing to do with the file system)

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx, you are limited with the size of your Developer Edition databases, but to something like 524PB.  Given the FAT32 limitations, though, you're going to have to split your database across multiple files / filegroups.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx for more information.

Comment: 'fraid you'd say that.
I am using a program (as a black box) that imports lotsa XML to my DB.
It goes over the size limit and fails.
Is there a way to make the DB automatically split itself to multiple files?

Comment: @bloodcell: no, this is the work of the DBA - SQL Server won't do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The FAT file limit applies to all files, no matter whether a database file or a video file.

So "yes"